# Parse notifications are not going through

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform

I have been using the same payload for the last 2 days without any issues sending to ios and android clients.
All of a sudden, at noon today, the nptifications stopped getting through. I dont even see them in the console.

Are there any known issues this afternoon?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with a double quote int he payload.

```
{
"aps" : {
"badge": 1,
    "alert" : {
        "body" : bla bla"
    }
},
"acme" : "offer"
}
```

the double quote in front of offer was wrong.